# separate debug info from go binary after the file has been built

Tags: go, binary, strip, ldflags

I know that `go build ldflags="-s -w"` would work. However, I cannot optain a `.debug` file or debug info archive. Is there any method to strip binary generated from `go build` command only?

I've tried `eu-strip` but the sizes of files are not the same.

- `with "-s -w" tag` : 62780680 Bytes
- `without "-s -w" tag`: 94617747 Bytes
- `not stripped yet .bin after eu-strip`: 77073712 Bytes

There are some other combination I've tried.

- `with "-s" tag`: 86700186 Bytes
- `after eu-strip`: 62780752 Bytes
- `with "-w" tag`: 69849906 Bytes
- `after eu-strip`: 62780784 Bytes

I noticed that the size of files that are built with `"-s"` or `"-w"` tags and stripped are very close to the one that is built with "-s -w" tags. Their sizes are still different though. Maybe eu-strip is not a suitable tool.

How can I separate debug information from non-stripped binary? I want to use such file to debug with dlv.

(ref of debug-info-directory: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/pkg/config/config.go)

Comment: "How do you strip go binary after the file has been built?" We don't. Please note that asking for tools is OT. More than 10 years ago upx did work.

Comment: Sorry for unclear description. Actually I like to know how to separate debug info from existing binary. I have a running process which cannot be shutdown but I need to use `dlv` to debug. The binary in the run is stripped so I need external debug info to debug.

Comment: Maybe you need [this](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/TsdC31np5wY/m/of0zsuWKBgAJ)?

Comment: Thank you, @kostix! I've realized my misconception regarding the strip command. I previously thought there was only one standard strip algorithm, which could lead to confusion when encountering different file sizes. Through testing, I've discovered that both objcopy and en-strip are effective. However, it's important to note that the debug information produced by eu-strip and objcopy is specific to the stripping method used. Therefore, they are not interchangeable, as debug info from eu-strip is only compatible with binaries stripped by eu-strip, and the same applies to objcopy.